# Finding domain of trigonometric function where we add k pi

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I don't understand how I need to solve domain of trigonometric functions where I have to add k pi or 2k pi

For example
$f(x)=\sqrt[2016]{e^{\frac{1}{sin\pi x}*\frac{x^3-11x^2+28x}{x^2-7x+6}}}$

I know to do every other condition in this problem except for condition that sinPI has to be different than zero

$sin\pi x \neq 0$

$\pi x \neq 0+k\pi , k \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$

Dividing whole expression with pi, we get that x has to be different than k.

What I am not sure about is how did kpi show up? I know why sinpix has to be different than zero, but calculation to x different than k is really confusing to me

Another example

$f(x)=\sqrt{16-x^2}+log(sin(x-\frac{3\pi }{x}))$
Again, other steps for finding domain are known to me, here's what I don't find understanding:

$sin(x-\frac{3\pi }{x})> 0$

$2k\pi +0< x-\frac{3\pi }{4}< \pi +2k\pi , k\epsilon \mathbb{Z}$

And from this point I know how to solve, now, why do we have 2kpi instead of just kpi?

Third example

$f(x)=\frac{tg^{-1}log\frac{x^2+2x}{x^2+9}}{arccos(\frac{x-1}{x-4})}$

$arccos\frac{x-1}{x-4}\neq 0$

$\frac{x-1}{x-4}\neq \frac{\pi }{2}+k\pi ,k\epsilon \mathbb{Z}$

And I know later calculations but here's what confuses me is why is it pi/2 now? Why not just pi or anything like examples above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigonometric functions are periodic functions. They will repeat their values after certain intervals.
In your first example, $\sin(\pi x) ≠ 0 $, the sine function gives value 0 for all integral multiples of $\pi$. (This additional condition you write by $\pi x ≠ k \pi$ ).

Same is the case with the other examples, it's just the interval after which the solutions repeat differs. So somewhere you have $k \pi$ and somewhere $2k \pi$.

The best way to do the second question is by drawing the graph of the left hand side of the inequality, you should be able to justify the answer then.